# How to re-run an android app even after closing

Tags: android

I would like to run an android app persistently. So at the event of crashing or accidentally closing the app should restart it by itself automatically. How can I do this? Is there any readily available app that does it?

Comment: That is not really an option. [Device manufacturers go to great lengths to stop apps after a while](https://dontkillmyapp.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run an Android app persistently, you can use the Android "sticky" service feature, which allows an app to run in the background even if the app is not actively in use. This can help ensure that the app stays running even if it is accidentally closed or crashes.

To create a sticky service in your Android app, you will need to add the START_STICKY flag to your service's onStartCommand method, like this:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    // Perform some action here, such as starting a background thread or
    // processing data from an intent

    // Return the "sticky" flag
    return START_STICKY
}
```

This will tell Android to keep the service running in the background, even if the app is not actively in use. The service will be restarted if the system needs to free up resources, or if the app is restarted by the user.

As for whether there are any readily available apps that can do this, there are many task manager or "booster" apps available on the Google Play Store that claim to be able to keep apps running persistently in the background. However, the effectiveness of these apps can vary, and some may not work as advertised. It is always a good idea to do some research and read reviews before downloading any third-party apps.

In general, the best way to ensure that your app runs persistently is to use the Android sticky service feature, as described above. This will give you the most control over how your app runs, and will help ensure that it stays running in the background as you intended.